# extraction folder in shared project throws access exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, mono

I have added zipped older to my project  - as embedded resource-  - in the shared part. and I would like to extract it, however I am getting access right exception. I thought that maybe Xamarin.Essentials and permission would solve this but still no help, plus this is file that I need in the shared part not platform based. Could you please advise how to extract folder in xamarin forms in shared project

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.




ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(
                Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory,"server.zip"),//zipPath 
                Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory //extractPath
            );
            //ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("/Users/erik/Documents/WorkPlace/app/Reader/Reader/server.zip", "/Users/erik/Documents/WorkPlace/app/Reader/Reader/NewDictionary");
```

Comment: which platform are you testing this on?

Comment: iOS, and I guess its worth saying that I run on macOS - mono

Comment: if the zip file is an embedded resource, why are you trying to extract it from `CacheDirectory`?  Embedded resources are not files and cannot be accessed using paths

Comment: that was a test, I don't know how to do it so I tried this

Comment: you will probably need to copy the zip file from resources to a folder first, then extract it